Estimating a complex integral for a probability problem: $HH$ is more likely to appear than $THT$ or $TTT$ in $n$ coin flips
The probability problem asks us to toss a coin $n$ times (actually $100$ times) and Alice gets a point whenever there is a $HH$ and Bob gets a point whenever there is a $THT$ or a $TTT$. Who is more likely to win?
[As an example, consider the sequence $THHHTHTHTTT$. This sequence gives $2$ points to ALice and $3$ points to Bob.]
Using (two separate) Markov chains and matrix multiplications (done on a computer), we found out that Alice is more likely to win (Alice wins $622452888834764723839990461444$ times while Bob wins $597223930770097681231606561162$ times when we have $100$ tosses). We tried it for several other $n$, and the graph shows that Alice is always more likely to win.

We verified this answer using a recursive solution (also done using a computer), so we believe that the answers are correct.
So we tried to do this analytically by looking at the generating function for the probabilities as such. We denote by $p_{n,k,TT}=\mathbb P(X_n=k|Y_{n-1}=T,Y_n = T)$ where $X_i$ is a random variable for the difference of scores between Alice and Bob after $i$-th toss, and $Y_j$ represents the outcome of the $j$-th toss. Similarly, we define $p_{n,k,TH},p_{n,k,HT},p_{n,k,HH}$. The recursion that comes out is the following:
$$
\begin{align}
p_{n,k,TT}&=\frac12(p_{n-1,k+1,TT}+p_{n-1,k,HT}) \\
p_{n,k,TH}&=\frac12(p_{n-1,k,HT}+p_{n-1,k,TT}) \\
p_{n,k,HT}&=\frac12(p_{n-1,k+1,TH}+p_{n-1,k,HH}) \\
p_{n,k,HH}&=\frac12(p_{n-1,k-1,TH}+p_{n-1,k-1,HH}) \\
\end{align}
$$
We define the generating function $\varphi_n(z) = \sum_k \mathbb P(X_n=k)z^k$ and define $\varphi_{n,TT}(z),\varphi_{n,TH}(z),\varphi_{n,HT}(z),\varphi_{n,HH}(z)$ as the respective conditional generating functions. Along with proper base cases, this gives $$
\varphi_n(z) = \frac1{2^n}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac1z & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & \frac1z & 0 & 1\\
0 & z & 0 & z\end{bmatrix}^{n-2}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ z\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now realizing that $$
\mathbb P(\text{Bob winning})={\frac 1 {2\pi i}}\int_C\left(\sum_{k<0}z^{-k-1}\right)\varphi_n(z)dz
$$
$$
\mathbb P(\text{Alice winning})={\frac 1 {2\pi i}}\int_{C'}\left(\sum_{k>0}z^{-k-1}\right)\varphi_n(z)dz
$$
for proper contours $C,C'$ we define later. Doing some complex analysis magic, we get $$\mathbb P(\text{Alice winning})-\mathbb P(\text{Bob winning})={\frac 1 {2\pi i}}\int_C {\frac {\varphi_n(z^{-1})-\varphi_n(z)} {1-z}}~\mathrm dz$$where $C$ is a contour satisfying $\max \{|z|: z\in C\}<1$ and containing the origin inside (the half radius circle should work).
Now we want to show that this integral is greater than $0$ for all $n\geq3$ but really stuck. We tried diagonalizing the matrix to understand $\varphi_n(z)$ but it was horrible.
Any help is appreciated.

It's not sufficient, but it's at least somewhat relevant that the expected number of points for $A$ is $\frac {n-1}4$ while for $B$ it is $2\times \frac {n-2}8=\frac {n-2}4$, so at least $A$'s expected score is higher.  You could compute the variance of each and use normal approximations but, of course, the distributions are dependent so the computation isn't so straightforward.

Another way to pose the complex-analysis question: Show that the residue of $\phi_n(z^{-1})/(1-z)$ at $z=0$ is always larger than that of $\phi_n(z^{})/(1-z)$.

On the graph, I assume that the horizontal axis is $n$, and the vertical axis is the probability of winning. Either Alice wins, or Bob wins, or they tie. For large $n$ values, the probability of a tie should be very small, so the sum of their probabilities of winning should be close to $1$, but the graph appears otherwise. Am I missing something?

Linguistic issues -- if we observe $THTTT$ is that 1 or 2 points for Bob?  Similarly is $HHHH$ 2 or 3 points for Alice?  You did not mention a "fresh start" property so I take the larger numbers in each case but I don't think everyone has this interpretation.

@user8675309 For $THTTT$, that's 2 points for Bob and 0 points for Alice. Similarly, for $HHHH$, it's 3 points for Alice and 0 for Bob. I should put an example, thank you for pointing that out.

are the methods here useful?

@mathworker21 That is pretty interesting. But I am really looking for a completely analytical solution, no computer help at all. But thanks regardless, will definiely look more into it.

@HackR Thanks for your response. I might have time later today to work on this problem. What exactly is your question? Would you be happy with an elementary argument that Alice has a strictly larger winning probability than Bob, or do you want a proof of this specifically using the contour integral formula?

@mathworker21 I would really love if this method can be salvaged. If not, some other argument is also appreciated!

@HackR It seems you have no properties of $\varphi_n$ that you have access to. What the paper I linked to above does is writes $\mathbb{P}[\text{Alice wins}] = \frac{1}{2}-A_n$ and finds a recurrence for $A_n$. Then you can use generating functions and contour integration to find asymptotics for $A_n$. Probably the same works here.

A large $n$ asymptotic of $\varphi_n$ is probably easier to deal with, and $n=100$ is definitely large enough.

@HackR Ok, how about this lol?

Conjecture: if Alice does not get a point for the first two coins, then both have the same probability of winning.

@leonbloy if you mean "forbidding sequences that start with HH" then it seems Alice wins (strictly) less often. In fact, it does not seem to be possible to reach the same probability of winning for both by imposing that the sequence must start with a length 2 word in a set. Who is more likely to win seems to change as a function of the length if you impose a start in {HT, TH} though (at first, ultimately it seems Alice wins.)

A natural conjecture based on the result for HH and HT in the beautiful paper linked by @mathworker21 is that, if $\Delta_n$ is the probability of Alice winning minus the probability of Bob winning for a game played with sequences of length $n$, then we should have $\Delta_n \sqrt{n} \to c$ for some constant $c$ as $n\to \infty$. The convergence seems to be quite fast.

@ThomasLehéricy No, I don't men "forbidding sequences that start with HH", only not counting that first pair as a point for Alice

@leonbloy then after testing it for $n\leq 19$ your conjecture is true for $n \in { 3, 6 }$ (I did not count $n\leq 2$) but seems to be false for every other $n$. Alice is less likely to win for $n \in { 4, 5, 9, 10 }$ and more likely for $n\in {7, 8 }$ and (conjecturally) for $n \geq 11$.

@ThomasLehéricy I believe the constant is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ by assuming the distribution is heuristically given by a negative binomial distribution (which numerically seems a very good approximation for large $n$). Here's a result https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/643092/coin-flip-game-hh-vs-ht-in-a-sequence-of-flips which also does find the same relation as in my question and the paper.

@HackR thank you for the very interesting link! We have $\frac 1 {2\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 0.28209479...$ while the sequence seems to converge towards $\approx 0.201$. I think the difference between the problem and the one you linked may cause the constant to be different.
